# Oracle Apex Data loader - 4 unique columns to check

Tags: oracle, key, unique, oracle-apex, loader

I have made a few data loader pages. Now I have to create/edit a data loader page to check on 4 columns of a unique key. Apex only allows 3.
How can I check on 4 columns instead of 3 columns

I'm using Oracle Apex 4.2

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try to add column to your table, which will be result of concatenation of your 4 unique columns, and set it as "unique". If it is not possible, create unique constraint in a table (I recommend to create this constraint in any case).